# Mouse coordinate to cnc position

Tags: java, communication

My name is Pascal and I'm 19 years old. For my internship I've to prove if it is possible to receive IR coordinates from a mouse and send it in Gcode position to a CNC machine.

The programming language is Java. This cannot be changed anymore.

The basic idea is to make a program that setups a communication with the mouse and cnc machine. I already have two programms that work separatly. It's called SimpleWrite and MouseCoordinates(both writed in Java). The SimpleWrite program, writew a certain message over a com port. The mousecoordinates makes a connection with the mouse and log the IR coordinates to the console.

Mouse ==> Computer ==> CNC machine.        .
IRcoordinates ==> Format to Gcode ==> sending over comport

So the main probles is: How can I combine these two programs (wich contains both a main method) to one working program? So the program starts the communication with the mouse and sends these coordinates (using the SimpleWrite program) formated in Gcode over the comport.

Im not asking to show me the solution but simple give some tips to search for. My only problem is that I'm not very good in programming java, so how does a program structure looks like if setting up these two programms into one working program?

On this project rests confidentiality, so its not actually a mouse but the concept does the same. The simplewrite program is open source.

SimpleWrite: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=214

Forgive me for my blurry english:).

Thanks in advance.

Greetings
Pascal

@Edit:

The programms are now combined. SimpleWrite gives me the message "Data verzonden" (means Data sended) and then connects the mouse and prints the coordinates to the console. Actually the sended data is still the messageString.

Now the first problem has been solved, the next problem is still a dark spot for me. The SimpleWrite program was originaly build to open a comport and sends a single String "messageString" over the comport. Combining the 2 programs is like the same as running them stand alone.

How can I format the incoming x and y coordinates to gcode and then, send a flow of gcode data like G0 X(x coordinate) Y(y coordinate) instead of a single outputStream.write(messageString.getBytes()); ?

So it will be like:
    G0 X30 Y30 
    G0 X31 Y31
    G0 X32 Y32
   and so on....

I dont know how many time there is between the incoming gcode and if the CNC machine will buffer these commands first(and how many he can buffer) and then execute them, but thats a third problem:).

The complete picture is now:
    Mouse coordinates to pc ==> OK!
    USB port opening ==> OK!
    USB port stream (single string) ==> OK!
    **Mouse x and y coordinates ==> Gcode NOT OK!
    Mouse gcode ==> CNC machine NOT OK!**

Thanks again.

Comment: If possible, take the parts you need, construct them in separate classes as required and call them in the order you need

Answer (score 0):

> How can I combine these two programs (which contains both a main method) to one working program?

This is the problem you have if I've correctly understood. In the two programs, change the `main()` method to `init()` and create a new program with a `main()` like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Program1.init();
    Program2.init();
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for answering! Thats what I meant but the SimpleWrite program sends the messageString = "Hello World". I want the massageString contains the incoming data from the mousecoordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the code so that first the setup stuff for the "mouse" and the COM port is handled. Then, take the rest of the "mouse reader" code and replace the thing that writes to the console with a call to a method that writes to the COM port. So, your new main method (probably in a new class) should look roughly like this:

```
/* open mouse input */
/* open COM output */
while (true) {
    /* read from mouse */
    /* reformat as gcode */
    /* write the data to the COM port */
}
```

Try to reuse the existing classes as much as possible without modifying them by calling their methods.